# Signum function

Tags: java, performance, reinventing-the-wheel, floating-point

This is the [Java `signum(double)` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Math.java#Math.signum%28double%29) I am trying to imitate:

> ```
> public static double signum(double d) {
>     return (d == 0.0 || Double.isNaN(d))?d:copySign(1.0, d);
> }
> ```

This is my version

```
public static double signum(double x) {
    return x != 0 ? x / abs(x) : 0;
}
```

I was thinking my method was not very readable, but I don't consider the Java method very readable, either. Is my method's readability okay? Also, how efficient is it, when compared to Java's `signum` method?

Comment: What is `abs(...)`? Is it Math.abs?

Comment: Note that your method does not handle `Double.NaN` so your code is not the same as the Java version. Additionally, your code is unclear about what `abs` is, and there does not appear to be any effort to actually test its performance relative to the Java native one.... why do you want to do it differently unless you know it will be faster? Is it faster? Is this a learning exercise?

Comment: @rolfl It's my own absolute value function (it works :P)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Floating-point division is probably the slowest basic arithmetic operation.  For this simple function, it's entirely avoidable.  I would also worry about whether the result of the division is *exactly* ±1.0.

There are three-and-a-half special cases evident in the model that you are trying to imitate; you've correctly handled two of them.

- `signum(Double.NaN)` should return `Double.NaN`.  Your version returns `Double.NaN`, but it is not obvious by inspection that it would do so.
- `signum(+0.0)` returns +0.0, as expected.
- `signum(-0.0)` returns +0.0, instead of [-0.0](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero), which is the model behaviour.
- `signum(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)` and `signum(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)` should return ±1.0, but your function incorrectly returns `Double.NaN`.